# Jenkins build periodically scheduler shows wrong timings

Tags: jenkins

I have scheduled my Jenkins job to run `everyday` at `4am(IST)` But it is showing the next run would be at `4:43:28 AM IST.`this is wrong. Ideally it should show `4am`. But Jenkins native host and docker container systems timing matching with local timings. Here no issues.

Even in my docker-compose file i already have below,

```
environment:
  - TZ=Asia/Kolkata
  - JAVA_ARGS="-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=Asia/Kolkata"
volumes:
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
```

[image]

Not sure what is wrong in my docker jenkins to show wrong timings in job scheduler. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should `0 4 * * *` like this. you entered wrong cron expression.

Fo more info about cron you can use this link https://crontab.guru/#0_4_*_*_*

Comment: `0 4 * * *` this shows would next run at `Friday, January 22, 2021 4:00:55 AM IST.` But warning shows as `Spread load evenly by using ‘H 4 * * *’ rather than ‘0 4 * * *’` i think i can ignore this warning msg and proceed with `0 4 * * *`